# twig template - how to render html inside twig template

Tags: html, twig, render

I am just trying to make my pagination script working through twig. When I send results of my php variable into twig as a twig variable {{pagination}} it shows raw html code:

```
Page <strong>3</strong> of 4&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="/search.php?pn=2"> Back</a> 
<span class="paginationNumbers">&nbsp; <a href="/search.php?pn=2">2</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
<span class="pagNumActive">3</span> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="/search.php?pn=4">4</a> &nbsp;
</span>&nbsp; <a href="/search.php?pn=4"> Next</a>
```

How can I render these html tags now?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe auto-escaping is turned on.
You can have a look at the [autoescape parameters](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html) for twig.

You can try wrapping your code between  `{% autoescape false %}` and `{% endautoescape %}`.

Comment: Although this works i decided to use @nostrzak 's solution with `| raw` filter, as it's more granular and may be applied to single variable usage leaving all else intact and safely escaped.

Comment: As, today, still works ❤️

Answer (score 8):

Use `{{ pagination | raw }}` for your output.

From documentation:

> The raw filter marks the value as being "safe", which means that in an
>   environment with automatic escaping enabled this variable will not be
>   escaped if raw is the last filter applied to it.

Comment: Yes I stumbled up on this while searching possible solution, for some reason it didn't work with the raw filter whatever I used it or not.

Comment: For me worked like a charm. Eg. to replace all spaces in a string with NBSP i had to use `stringVariable|replace({' ': '&nbsp;'})|raw`.
By the way, `replace(' ', '&nbsp;')` (usage with two params, not single dictinary) didn't work for me either.

Comment: I need to avoid autoescape without modify teh template just based on content like this

Comment: I need to avoid autoescape without modify the template just based on content like this
variable x="{%autoescape false%}abc{%endautoescape%}"
obviusly doesn't work
but I can't modify the template is a macro to print a simple table 
I don't know which content should be not escaped until the template is rendered
There should be a function like render(x)

Answer (score 3):

I used this between your

```
{% autoescape false %} 
{{ body }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

It worked for me